# How do I create a cert from CSR and root CA in Python with pyOpenSSL?

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, cryptography

In Python using OpenSSL, given I have a self-signed root CA and a certificate signing request (CSR), how then do I create a certificate from the CSR signed by my root CA?  (did I say that right?)

```py
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL

# create a self-signed root CA cert
rootkey = crypto.PKey()
rootkey.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
rootca = crypto.X509()
rootca.get_subject().CN = "my_root_ca"
rootca.gmtime_adj_notBefore(10)
rootca.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
rootca.set_issuer(rootca.get_subject())
rootca.set_pubkey(rootkey)
rootca.sign(rootkey, 'sha256')

# create a CSR with a code in CN
csrkey = crypto.PKey()
csrkey.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
csr = crypto.X509Req()
csr.get_subject().CN = '4854996413a0bcffb73b956d63f728d10e6d97bb'
csr.set_pubkey(csrkey)
csr.sign(csrkey, 'sha256')

# save files
open('rootCA.pem', 'wb').write(crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, rootca))
open('rootCA.key', 'wb').write(crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, rootkey))
open('verificationCert.csr', 'wb').write(crypto.dump_certificate_request(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, csr))
```

How do I now sign that CSR with the root ca in python?
(again, sorry if the vernacular isn't correct, please feel free to correct)

Here is the equivalent command line I'm trying to replicate in Python:

```sh
openssl x509 -req -in verificationCert.csr -CA rootCA.pem -CAkey rootCA.key -CAcreateserial -out verificationCert.pem -days 500 -sha256
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why? Why not just use `OpenSSL`?

Comment: I do want to use openssl, but through the pyOpenSSL wrapper in python code.  I don't want to use the openssl command line tool bc of (1) where this is getting deployed, (2) consistency with the rest of the app this is going into, and (3) it should be doable in code so that's what I want to learn.

Comment: I'd suggest using the cryptography library. (cryptography.io). It's developed by the same people, and has a better API.

Comment: @Legorooj Have an example creating a cert from a CSR with cyptography.io?

Comment: @noahcoad I don't use x509. You can find the docs [here](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/)

Comment: Those docs seems to be out of date, generating errors. generate_private_key() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'public_exponent' and 'backend'